# What are some good GUI interfaces available for Octave other than the original one?

Tags: matlab

I am using Octave 5.2 (as of Nov 2020). I find the interface, especially the editor not so good looking like the MATLAB editor. For instance, the MATLAB editor recognizes the global variables, commands, repeated variables, links the if, for loops etc. Some interface that can do this for Octave?

Recognizing repeated variables is something interesting and makes my work easier. I'd certainly want this.

Also highlighting certain variables for preallocation and other warnings.

Also, I realize that the plotting is too slow in Octave. I plot finite element meshes often. It's too slow. I can literally see Octave drawing the figures. However, MATLAB completes the same figure in a fraction of a second. So please suggest some fast plotting tool that can be interfaced with octave if possible. Or any alternative.

Thanks in advance.